# Encoding LR to MS - which plug-in?

Tags: ms, microphone

I am trying to find a plug-in that encodes LR-signals to MS. I have two AT3032 that I want to use as a stereo pair, and this is what I need to do (as per instructions):

"Match the mic response with normal EQ (left/right channels) then using an LR to MS plugin (or mid/side encoder and decoder) or EQ that operates on the Side channel (right) only you can boost the lows. Then use stereo width enhancement plugins to adjust the overall stereo image. The basic shuffling of the lows should get you quite far."

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

dunno if thats what you are looking for but there is a free plug called voxengo msed, that does ms encoding/decoding, as far as i understand http://www.voxengo.com/group/free-vst-plugins/

Comment: i like this one because it gives you level control of each channel within the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Brainworx plug ins. They have extensive MS specific stuff. Their EQ plugs will do what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

There's also the free +Matrix plugin from Tom "Soundhack" Erbe.

Answer (score 0):

The waves [S1 Imager](http://waves.com/Content.aspx?id=275) offers settings for input (L/R) and output (M/S) configurations. In most cases people would use it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Air Stereo Widener has a preset that expands a mono source